# Verifying the version of .Net Being used by web forms site

Tags: asp.net

I installed .Net 4.5 and have targetFramework="4.5" in my web.config file but on an error page I saw this:

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17020

How can I verify it is really using 4.5?

Comment: I believe targetFramework is only used for compilation, not runtime. So you're looking at the wrong setting.

Comment: Mystere Man IIS App Poll Version options are only v4.0.30319 and 2.0.50727 even though I do have 4.5 installed. There is no worker process to be set since this is not compiled code and it is a web forms site (not application).

Adrian Godong What setting should I be looking at?

Comment: @MystereMan 4.5 uses the 4.0 runtime, much like how 3.0 and 3.5 used the 2.0 runtime.

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete You may not realize it, but if ASP.NET code is running, there is a worker process with a .NET version set. However, see my comment above; 4.0 is the correct runtime version for a 4.5 application (page, assembly, whatever)

Comment: @AndrewBarber I know 4.0 is for 4.5 but it is also for 4.0. Do we know the subversions that corolate to 4.5? Do you know how I would check the worker process and what process I would check?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try adding a simple .ASPX file that uses some [new 4.5 stuff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868.aspx#web) and see if you can load it.

The `TextMode` property of `TextBox` is a new HTML5 feature.  This should create an [HTML5 *type=number*](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html) input:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="Number" />
```

Comment: Geez, tough crowd.  What, not philosophically pure enough?

Comment: Seems like a quick, accurate, though certainly 'dirty' way to do it.

Comment: Yes dirty but that does not matter to me, I will give it a shot and see what happens

Comment: Well it was dirty but making a textbox with the mode set to number produced the HTML 5 type.

Answer (score 0):

you should try this

```
string version = System.Environment.Version.ToString();
Response.Write(version);
```

Comment: That only returns "4" and as you can see in my post I know the number reported by the server but is that the correct number for 4.5?

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete are you sure you only get 4, because I get this value from my machine. framework version: 4.0.30319.17929

Comment: That is what I got when I wrote it out to a label but the real question is if that number you get (or the one I posted in first post) is for 4.0 or 4.5